# Changing a column in the Database with a cron job

Tags: node.js, cron, scheduled-tasks

I am building a full stack project, the frontend can send a date to the server (Nodejs) and right now the server creates a cron job that edits a column called `isActive` in the database which is of type `boolean`.

I am using the [Node schedule npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) in order to schedule the cron jobs and I am wondering if having a cron job that edits the `isActive` column is a good idea.

The main problem that I am thinking could happen is:
What happens if a user wants to change the `isActive` column on a specific record in a week from now but then they changed their mind and they want to cancel that. Is there a way to cancel that cron job or is there a way to get some kind of reference to that particular cron job?

I am very new to cron jobs so I am not sure how to work with them yet.

Thank you in advance for your help

The cron job is working as expected but I am not sure how to handle canceling that cron job for a specific user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to cancel a specific user.

Demo,
Two users (user1 and user2) scheduled at the first time on weekend.

But user2 want to cancel before weekend, so only user1 update isActive column.

#### Code as `time.js` file.

```js
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
const moment = require('moment')

// All users want to cancel for editIsActive()
let users = [
    {
        user : 'user1',
        isCancel : false
    },
    {
        user : 'user2',
        isCancel : false
    }
];

// Your database to update here except canceled user
function editIsActive(item) {
    if (!item.isCancel) {
        console.log(`${item.user} is edited a isActive column`);
    }
}

// user 2 canceled for editIsActive()
const some_user_cancel_job = schedule.scheduleJob('5 * * * * *', () => {
    if (!users[1].isCancel) {
        console.log('user 2  want to cancel to edit on xx:xx:5 (week day)' + moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
        users[1].isCancel = true
    }
});

// Main cron job scheduler
const cron_job = schedule.scheduleJob('10 * * * * *', () => {
    console.log('cron job called on every xx:xx:10 (week end)' + moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
    users.forEach((item) => {
        editIsActive(item)
    })
});

// All scheduled cron jobs clear in here
const clear_job = schedule.scheduleJob('6 * * * *', () => {
    console.log('Canceled all cron jobs on next Monday' + moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
    some_user_cancel_job.cancel()
    cron_job.cancel()
    clear_job.cancel()
});
```

#### Result

```
$ node time.js
user 2  want to cancel to edit on xx:xx:5 (week day)12/28/2022 16:02:05
cron job called on every xx:xx:10 (week end)12/28/2022 16:02:10
user1 is edited a isActive column
cron job called on every xx:xx:10 (week end)12/28/2022 16:03:10
user1 is edited a isActive column
cron job called on every xx:xx:10 (week end)12/28/2022 16:04:10
user1 is edited a isActive column
cron job called on every xx:xx:10 (week end)12/28/2022 16:05:10
user1 is edited a isActive column
Canceled all cron jobs on next Monday12/28/2022 16:06:00
```

All schedule time is not real data.
You need to see [manual](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule#readme)

Example) every Sunday at 2:30pm:

```
const job = schedule.scheduleJob({hour: 14, minute: 30, dayOfWeek: 0}, function(){
  console.log('Time for tea!');
});
```